# sqlite3 database got encrypted?

Tags: database, sqlite

I was doing some processing on my sqlite3 database power ran out and when I ran DB browser for sqlite3 to open my above mentioned database it prompted me to enter a key that was used to encrypt the database which I never did. I looked in my directory I have a new .db-journal file which I think should help me recover that I have absolutely no idea how to do it. If anyone has had this problem and can help me out I'd really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite transaction recovery mechanism assumes that the storage system does not change any part of the file that was not written.

But in your case, the beginning of the database file got corrupted, so the database structure is lost.
You have to restore the data from the backup.

Comment: is there any automatic backup that sqlite3 preforms or should I just use my manual backup?

Comment: There is no automatic backup.